# Sublime Text 3 - Module Functions Suggestions?

Tags: python, module, sublimetext3

I've been looking around here but I haven't finded what I was searching, so I hope it's not answer around here. If it is, I would delete my question.

I was wondering if Sublime Text can suggest you functions from a module when you write "module.function". For example, if I write "import PyQt4", then sublime Text suggests me "PyQt4.QtCore" when I write "PyQt4.Q".

For now, I'll installed "SublimeCodeIntel" and just does it but for only some modules (like math or urllib). It's possible to configure it for any module? Or you can recommend me any other plugin?

Thanks for reading!

PD: also, could be possible to configute it also for my own modules? I mean, for example, module that I have written and are in the same folder as the current file I'm editing.

Answer (score 0):

`SublimeCodeIntel` will work for any module, as long as it's indexed. After you first install the plugin, indexing can take a while, depending on the number and size of third-party modules you have in `site-packages`. If you're on Linux and have multiple `site-packages` locations, make sure you define them all in the settings. I'd also recommend changing `"codeintel_max_recursive_dir_depth"` to 25, especially if you're on OS X, as the default value of 10 may not reach all the way into deep directory trees.

Make sure you read through all the settings, and modify them to suit your needs. The README also contains some valuable information for troubleshooting, so if the indexing still isn't working after a while, and after restarting Sublime a few times, you may want to delete the database and start off fresh.

Comment: I have configured the `"codeintel_max_recursive_dir_depth"` and I put my own PYTHONPATH as `"C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages"` (because I'm using windows) and it doesn't work. I haven't changed the PATH one because I don't know what it means. 
I have also erased the ".codeintel" folder to restart indexing. Any other suggestion? :(

Comment: @user3524896 - try commenting out your `PYTHONPATH` definition and try again. There are other directories in the path besides the one you listed, so you'd need to add all of them in order for it to work.

Comment: Already done and still not working. But it worked with costum modules that are on the same forlder as the file I'm editing but big modules (like networkx or PyQt4) aren't working...